# How to track jQuery Plugin usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, analytics, tracking

I'm about to finish a jQuery plugin.

I will sell licences. Open source project will be able to use it for free. I don't care if some people will use it although they are not allowed to.

But it would be cool to track the usage of the script.

I don't want to spy anyone or track them to see if they have bought a licence. It simply would be cool if I could see how often it is actually used.

The only thing I want to know is: Is successful? How many people actually use it?

PS: Maybe there exists a method that doesn't need any of these evil, sniffy tracking scripts.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I certainly wouldn't like it if a plugin I was using started sending data behind my back

Comment: If you plan on doing that, you need to warn the users that data (**even if it's only their IP**) will be sent to your server for tracking/statistics purposes.

Comment: Yep guys. I totally agree with you. Is there another solution to do something like that. I don't need to store anything. I should be working like a visit counter on a website.

Tracking is always a critical point but it would be truly awesome if there was a service like Google Analytics for developers.

Comment: @jurihandl Can't you just track downloads? That would be much more acceptable, and you'd even be able to use Google Analytics itself!

Comment: Downloads will be tracked anyway. Due to the fact that the plugin can be used multiple times it would be interesting how manny times it is used in total.
I'm not a tracking freak or anything like that I simply search for a solution that gives me good feedback about my plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You could just write a JSONp request into your plugin which pings your web server with the required information each time the init is called on your code:

```
function init() {
    $.ajax({  
            type:"GET",        
            url: "http://www.myplugin.com/tracking.php",
            data: {
               // All my lovely personal information
            }, 
            dataType: "jsonp", 
            timeout: 200000
        });  
}
```

But **please** give a thought to all the reasons that you shouldn't do the above.

Comment: Yep. That solution came to my mind before. Like you said there are many reasons why you shouldn't use that and you're totally right. Actually I was searching for a solution where I don't have to track users like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would do this by exposing a web service and having your script pass the data through it.

You should definitely tell your users what your doing.

However, I believe adding this code to a plugin could make an otherwise successful script unsuccessful. Or at the least the users will just remove it.

Comment: Yep. You're right. The main question is: how to track the usage of a script without some "evil" tracking code that will scare users.

Comment: You could post the script in a blog with a comments section and see how people respond.  People often like to say thank you, suggest new features, and ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not 100% accurate, I think the best solution is to:

- Track product downloads
- Set up or rent a CDN and track requests
- Track "Thank you"s, user reactions, feedback